# Resetting iPhone Safari's viewport after user scales

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, viewport

Does anyone know how I can get the iPhone Safari viewport to reset to a scale of my choice are a user has scaled using pinch?
It seems that although I can use `jQuery` to change the scale when ever I like by:

```
$('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=640, maximum-scale=0.5');
```

As soon as the user has scaled, there is no way of changing the scale?

I ideally need to let the user scale, so turning off user scaling is a last resort.
It looks like it's not possible.
I've considered using `jQuery` to reload the page, but this isn't ideal but will test now and report back.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Reloading doesn't work - user scale value is remembered.

Comment: what's wrong with set the maximum-scale and user-scalable??

Comment: possible duplicate of [scaling image on pinch gesture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356116/scaling-image-on-pinch-gesture)