# scaling image on pinch gesture

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, touch, pinch

I'm using the jQuery [touchy](https://github.com/HotStudio/touchy) plugin for detecting the pinch event to give users the ability to zoom in/out on an image.  Here's the gist of my code:

```
var w = 800,
    h = 600;
$('img').on('touchy-pinch', function (e, $target, data) {
    $(this).css({
        width: w * data.scale,
        height: h * data.scale
    });
});
```

Where the custom data object contains the following:

- scale
- previousScale
- currentPoint
- startPoint
- startDistance

It works fine on the first pinch, but once my fingers leave the screen and then I try to do it again, the image re-scales back up.  How can I modify my handler so that the image continues where it left off rather than re-scale?  Using the data's previousScale didn't help since the previousScale just gets reset as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not resetting your vars w and h to their post-scaled values, only the css, so the style reverts back to 800x600 on another scale event. You need a persistent w and h that are set to `w*data.scale` and `h*data.scale` on the scale event.